# Is there any way to get asana tag color?

Tags: asana

I'd like to get tag colors. I haven't find anything related to tag color in the API. Is there any way to do that using Asana API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** We now expose the `color` property of both projects and tags! Check out the [developer documentation](https://asana.com/developers/documentation) for more details, but the upshot is you can now get and set `color` to one of the following values: dark-pink, dark-green, dark-blue, dark-red, dark-teal, dark-brown, dark-orange, dark-purple, dark-warm-gray, light-pink, light-green, light-blue, light-red, light-teal, light-yellow, light-orange, light-purple, light-warm-gray.

Or `null`, of course. But why would you want that? Life is better in color ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is **DEPRECATED**, see my other, updated answer. (StackOverflow seems to suggest that you shouldn't change the meaning of an answer, so I'm leaving this one here and making a new one to be safe.)

We don't currently expose that - colors are a fairly new property of tags and we haven't added it to the API model yet, but I'll add it to our list of API requests!

Comment: Would be great to get access to this through the API so we could sync colours for all our tags between our users and use them in emails we send from the API.